# How many integer pairs $(x,y)$ satisfy $|x|^m+|y|^m=r$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

**First let me put the question succinctly:**

For whole numbers $m$ and $r$ how many integer pairs $(x,y)$ satisfy the equation $|x|^m+|y|^m=r$?

**Now for exposition:**

For some motivations to this questions check out: [Computing $\beta(\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{m})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2748120/computing-beta-frac1m-frac1m)

For a $m=2$ the result can be given in general which I will do below but the sake of example consider the case $m=2$ and $r=45$. Then there are $8$ integer pairs (x,y) such that $x^2+y^2=45$ and this can be seen in the picture below:

[image: A circle with radius square root of 45.]
Generally speaking for the number of integer pairs that satisfy $x^2+y^2=r$
is equal to $$4\sum_{d|r} \chi_2(r)$$ where $$\chi_2(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    -1       & \quad \text{if } x \text{ is congruent to 3 mod 4}\\
    1        & \quad \text{if } x \text{ is congruent to 1 mod 4}\\
    0        & \quad \text{if } x \text{ is congruent to 0 mod 2} 
 \end{cases}$$

Now let's look at a case for $m\neq 2$. Consider the case $m=4$ and $r=97$. There are $8$ integer pairs that satisfy the equation $x^4+y^4=97$ as seen in the diagram below.

[image]

Is there a way to know in general how many solutions there are to $|x|^m+|y|^m=r$?

Comment: Why do you think there must be a solution that takes the form of a divisor sum? The case $m=2$ is special because of its relation to complex multiplication (which has $x^2+y^2$ factoring as $(x+iy)(x-iy)$). I see no reason to believe that this generalizes to higher powers, although it's conceivable there is still an answer to the title question by different methods.

Comment: I may speculate this by writing $\chi_2$ as if there is a more general $\chi_m$. There is no reason this would result in some divisor sum. I don't think I really imply this is the case.

Comment: I think you are off by a factor of 4 in your definition of $\chi_2$.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't look like $\chi_3$ is very nice. Here's a table of the first hundred values: {2, -1, -2, -1, -2, 1, -2, 2, 2, 1, -2, 1, -2, 1, 2, -1, -2, -2, -2, 
1, 2, 1, -2, -2, 0, 1, 0, 3, -2, -1, -2, -1, 2, 1, 4, 0, -2, 1, 2, 
-2, -2, -1, -2, 1, -2, 1, -2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, -2, 1, 2, -4, 2, 1, -2, 
-1, -2, 1, -2, 2, 4, -1, -2, 1, 2, -3, -2, 2, -2, 1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -2, 
1, -2, 1, -2, -3, 2, 1, 2, -2, -2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, -2, 0, -2, 0}

Comment: If $x^m+y^m=0$ then $\frac{x}{y}=({-1})^{1/m}$ and this is enough for me to think that complex multiplication plays a significant role in the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76417/discussion-between-mason-and-mario-carneiro).

Comment: See also: https://oeis.org/A175362 ($m=3$)

Comment: More information on the sum of cubes can be found here: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/22/Ford/silverman331-340.pdf

Comment: @MarioCarneiro. Did you produce that using Wolfram Alpha? And can you share the code?

Comment: More on the sum of cubes: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Broughan/broughan25.pdf

Comment: I used mathematica, not wolfram alpha, and I've had little success running arbitrary mathematica code in alpha without it getting confused by the natural language stuff. Here's a straightforward calculation of those numbers (I didn't keep the original code, but this works too):
`count[n_] := With[{t = Floor[n^(1/3)]}, Sum[Boole[x^3 + y^3 == n], {x, -t, t}, {y, -t, t}]]`
`chi3[n_] := chi3[n] = count[n] - Sum[chi3[k], {k, Complement[Divisors[n], {n}]}]`
`Table[chi3[n], {n, 100}]`